# Django registration

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно регистрировать пользователей на сайте через админ панель Django. Нужно всего 4 поля. Это: username, name, pass, id. Никак не могу найти инфу как это реализовать. Опыта у меня очень мало, прошу помочь если кто нибудь знает как это можно реализовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Создай модель User (могу сослаться на документацию, но приведу пример кода:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    passwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   #                            ^
   #                            |
   #                            |
   #                     ТАК ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ СТОИТ!!!
   #                  ПАРОЛИ НАДО ШИФРОВАТЬ!!!!!!
```

И зарегистрируй её в admin.py

```
admin.site.register(User)
```

Кстати, у админки очень много всяких возможностей, да и у Джанги в целом. Почитай книгу "Django 2.1 на практике" https://www.pdfdrive.com/django-21-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-e184062061.html . Я её не до конца дочитал, и уже знаю, как создать быстрый пиратский сайт со всяческими примочками вроде форума (на примере будет создаваться сайт объявлений). Удачи в прочтении!